# How to print substring contained between braces?

Tags: c++, substring

I'm writing a function, which is *supposed* to output whatever is between curly braces in string
(e.g. `hello world` for `text{hello world}`).
But it isn't outputting anything when I try running it. Do you have any idea what could be wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    start:    
    std::string funct;
    
    std::cout << "-->";
    std::cin >> funct;
    
    int temp = 0;

//focus on what's down here V
    
    string word;
    if (funct.find("text") != string::npos)
        {
            for(int i=0; i<1; i){
                if(funct.at(temp)=='}'){i=1;}
                    else{
                    temp += temp;
                    word = funct.at(temp + 5);}
            }
        cout<<word<<endl;    
        }
    
    cout<<endl<<endl<<"=================================================="<<endl<<endl;
    goto start;
    
    return 0;
}
```

*Edit, 'funct' is the raw user input, and 'temp' is just a placeholder integer.

Comment: Please post a [mre] (i.e. share a program not a snippet).

Comment: What is funct?  temp is defined.

Comment: @Jorengarenar. OP wants to create a function that takes an input that looks like `text{...}`, and function should return everything inside the braces

Comment: @smac89 Oh, makes more sense.

Comment: Try `cout << word << endl;` instead of `cout << endl << word;`

Comment: Could you explain why you believe your code should work? (Especially how it determines where the opening brace is?)

Comment: *"`//focus on what's down here V`"* -- not a great approach. Better would be to simplify what comes before that line so that we are almost forced to focus on what comes after. The part of the main function that comes before that line could be simply `int main(){
    std::string funct = "text{hello world}";
    int temp = 0;`, which is not much to focus on, right? You'd have to also remove the `goto` line from this example since I removed the label. (You'd be better off removing the `goto` from your full program as well.)

Comment: I ran your code and got an infinite loop. When I fixed that, there was plenty of output: `-->h


==================================================`. That's a far cry from not "outputting anything".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand, you want a function that is parsing a string and printing whatever is within a construction like `'text{...}'`
Here is a few issues in your code:

1. `std::cin >> funct` will only read a word (whitespace separated text). If you want to get an entire line, use `std::getline(std::cin, yourString)`
2. You look for an occurrence of 'text', but do not save the index:

```cpp
    if (funct.find("text") != string::npos)
```

3. `std::string::at()` is indeed a safe way of accessing an element of a string, however your program may terminate with `std::out_of_range` exception if not handled.
4. `std::string::at()` returns not a string, but a char&

   word = funct.at(temp + 5);

Here's my implementation of a function, that finds `text{...}` construct in a string and prints the contents:

```
#include <iostream>
//using reference, so that the object is not copied
void print_text(const std::string& string) {
        //starting and ending points of the needed text
        size_t start = string.find("text"),
        end;
        //if "text" is not found, exit function
        if (start == std::string::npos)
                return;
        //adding to start, so that it points to the last character of "test"
        start += sizeof("text") - 2;
        try {
                //ignoring all the spaces after "text"
                while (isspace(string.at(++start)));
                //testing for the open brace before the text
                if (string.at(start) != '{')
                        return;
                end = start;
                ++start;
                //testing for the closing brace after the text needed
                while (string.at(++end) != '}');
                //printing the substring if all the conditions are met
                std::cout <<  string.substr(start, end - start) << '\n';
        }
        //any time we reach the end of the string, we bail printing nothing
        catch(std::out_of_range) {
                return;
        }
}

int main() {
        print_text(std::string("sample text{test1}"));
        print_text(std::string("sample space text {test2}"));
        print_text(std::string("empty sample text{}"));
        print_text(std::string("sample text{test4} some after"));
        print_text(std::string("sample forgot closing text{test5"));
        print_text(std::string("sample forgot starting texttest6}"));
        print_text(std::string("sample forgot starting text test7}"));
        print_text(std::string("sample extra characters text hi {test8}"));
}
```

Output:

```
test1
test2

test4
```

Note:
You can effectively ask a user input in the main function and pass the string in `print_text` function, it would work.
Keep in mind, that it would only print the first occurrence of `text{}`, if you need any number of occurrences found, comment this reply.

Comment: *"I did not quite get how the code you've provided should work"* -- This might make it hard for you to answer the question that was asked ("what could be wrong", not "what is another approach to use").

Comment: @JaMiT. I agree, but it does not seem like a working code, so at least I can provide my implementation. Any answer is better than no answer at all.

Comment: *"Any answer is better than no answer at all."* -- this is not the view put forth in [answer] (the "Answer well-asked questions" section).

Comment: @JaMiT. I hope, you'll like the edited version more. I'm new to stackoverflow, don't know all the rules yet. Thanks for the article and pointing out my mistakes.